# Java String/Regex Replace

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm quite new to regex. Not sure how to do the follow:

Replace ":p_id" with a specific value.

For example when I simply want to replace ":p_id1" with a value, it also replaced ":p_id10" with the same value which is not what I want.

It's also possible for the ":p_id"'s to have punctuation before or after them e.g. "=:p_id1)"

Any advice?

Comment: Just go follow a regex tutorial, it will teach you all of the basics.

Comment: Providing the code you actually use for this procedure would help us understand what you are looking for.  I would also suggest to take a look at [this Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  It might help you understand how to fix it on your own (it feels better to do it yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\b` (word boundary) operator

```
myString.replaceAll(":p_id1\\b","some replacement");
```

See [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) > [Boundary matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I did have "\\b:p_id1\\b" before but that didn't seem to work. I definitely have to go and read some regex tutorials again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead at the end of your Pattern.

For instance:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":p_id\\d(?!\\d)");
String example = ":p_id1 :p_id10";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
while (matcher.find()) System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Output:

```
:p_id1
```

Comment: It's also possible for the ":p_id"'s to have punctuation before or after them e.g. =:p_id1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pattern I made:

```
 ^[=]{0,1}:p_id1\b[=]{0,1}
```

This matches strings like:

```
:p_id1
=:p_id1
:p_id1=
```

but doesn't match (for instance):

```
:p_id10
```